# How to verify if variable type is an array in Java languge

Tags: java

I'm new to java.
Please let me know how to verify if variable type is an array in Java languge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With any object, you can do this:

```
Class clazz = myObject.getClass();

if( clazz.isArray() ) {
    // ... array specific stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any type that is suffixed by [] is an array type.